# How to properly print this markup in php

Tags: php, html

How to print this markup in php?

```
<a href="javascript:AddItem('$node->title')" class="showmessage"
OnClick="show_alert()"><img class="atwatw" src="/files/button.gif" border="0" /></a>
```

I tried this but nada....

```
<?php print '<a href="javascript:AddItem(\'' . $node->title') . '" class="showmessage"
OnClick="show_alert()">' . '<img class="atwatw" src="/files/button.gif" border="0" /></a>' ?>
```

Comment: have you tried with `echo` instead of `print` ?

Comment: The syntax highlighting on this site should have alerted you - Your quotes in your PHP code isn't balanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just get the HTML code out of the PHP source like

```
//PHP code
?>

<a href="javascript:AddItem('<?php $node->title; ?>')" class="showmessage"
OnClick="show_alert()"><img class="atwatw" src="/files/button.gif" border="0" /></a>

<?php
//Continue with your PHP here
```

Now if you want to just have it in PHP, then use printf maybe

```
printf("<a href=\"javascript:AddItem('%s')\" class=\"showmessage\"
OnClick=\"show_alert()\"><img class=\"atwatw\" src=\"/files/button.gif\" border=\"0\" /></a>",$node->title);
```

More of a less escaped character edition:

```
printf('<a href="javascript:AddItem(\'%s\')" class="showmessage"
OnClick="show_alert()"><img class="atwatw" src="/files/button.gif" border="0" /></a>',$node->title);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to enclose it in php tags:

```
<?php print '<a href="javascript:AddItem(\'' . $node->title  . '\')" class="showmessage" OnClick="show_alert()"><img class="atwatw" src="/files/button.gif" border="0" /></a>' ?>
```

If not:

```
<a href="javascript:AddItem('<?=$node->title?>')" class="showmessage" OnClick="show_alert()"><img class="atwatw" src="/files/button.gif" border="0" /></a>
```

Comment: I can't it has to be enclosed inside <?php ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo '<a href="javascript:AddItem(\'' . $node->title .'\')" class="showmessage"
OnClick="show_alert()"><img class="atwatw" src="/files/button.gif" border="0" /></a>'; ?>
```